# Retrieve SP500 index historical data from InteractiveBroker API

Tags: python, interactive-brokers

The code below can retrieve historical stock data from InteractiveBroker API. However, it doesn't return value for SP500 whose symbol is 'SPX'.
The error is: `Error 200, reqId 6: No security definition has been found for the request, contract: Stock(symbol='SPX', exchange='SMART', currency='USD')`

What should be changed to get SPX open,high,low,close,vol data? (I include TSLA to show that this code works for stock). Many thanks.

```
from ib_insync import *;
import pandas as pd;

ib = IB()
ib.connect('127.0.0.1', 7496, clientId=1)

# Import ticklist

ticker_list=['TSLA','SPX']
def extract_data(duration_period, bar_period):
    global full_data

    full_data = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in ticker_list:
        print( '--', i);

        contract = Stock(i, 'SMART', 'USD')

        ib.reqHeadTimeStamp(contract, whatToShow='TRADES', useRTH=True)
        bars = ib.reqHistoricalData(
            contract,
            endDateTime='',
            # durationStr='1 D', barSizeSetting='1 hour',
            durationStr=duration_period, barSizeSetting=bar_period,
            whatToShow='TRADES',
            useRTH=False,
            formatDate=1)
        # print(bars)
        try:
            df = util.df(bars)
            df = df.drop(['average', 'barCount'], axis=1)
            df['ticker'] = i
            full_data = pd.concat([full_data, df])
        except:
            print('error tic: ', i)
    return full_data


extract_data('1 D','1 hour')
print(full_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for stocks, not indexes. From the [documentation](https://ib-insync.readthedocs.io/api.html#ib_insync.contract) you can see differentiation between the two and how to use them:

```
classib_insync.contract.Stock(symbol='', exchange='', currency='', **kwargs)
classib_insync.contract.Index(symbol='', exchange='', currency='', **kwargs)
```

Which means you can just add an extra conditional and specify the exchange where you define `contract`:

```
    if type == 'Stock':
        contract = Stock(ticker, 'SMART', 'USD')
    elif type == 'Index':
        contract = Index(ticker, 'CBOE', 'USD')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `contract = Stock(i, 'SMART', 'USD')` but SPX is **not** a stock. Check if there is `Index` function. Or you can use something like:

```
contract = Contract()
contract.symbol = "SPX"
contract.secType = "IND"
contract.currency = "USD"
contract.exchange = "CBOE"
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace Stock(i, 'SMART', 'USD') with Stock(i, 'CBOE', 'USD') for the SPX contract.

```
from ib_insync import *
import pandas as pd

ib = IB()
ib.connect('127.0.0.1', 7496, clientId=1)

ticker_list = ['TSLA', 'SPX']


def extract_data(duration_period, bar_period):
    global full_data

    full_data = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in ticker_list:
        print('--', i)

        if i == 'SPX':
            contract = Index(i, 'CBOE', 'USD')
        else:
            contract = Stock(i, 'SMART', 'USD')

        ib.reqHeadTimeStamp(contract, whatToShow='TRADES', useRTH=True)
        bars = ib.reqHistoricalData(
            contract,
            endDateTime='',
            durationStr=duration_period, barSizeSetting=bar_period,
            whatToShow='TRADES',
            useRTH=False,
            formatDate=1)

        try:
            df = util.df(bars)
            df = df.drop(['average', 'barCount'], axis=1)
            df['ticker'] = i
            full_data = pd.concat([full_data, df])
        except:
            print('error tic: ', i)
    return full_data


extract_data('1 D', '1 hour')
print(full_data)
```